# If a function $f$ is continuous on $Q$, is analytic in the interior of $Q$, and admits the bound $|f(z)|\leq m_i$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis

**Let $Q$ be a closed square centered at the origin, and let $S_1, S_2, S_3$ and $S_4$ be an enumeration of its sides. If a function $f$ is continuous on $Q$, is analytic in the interior of $Q$, and admits the bound $|f(z)|\leq m_i$, a constant, for every $z$ on $S_j (1\leq j\leq 4)$, then $|f(0)|\leq m_1m_2m_3m_4$. Justify this statement.**

I know that $\int_{Q}f(z)dz=0$ for the cauchy theorem and that $|f(z)|$ reaches its maximum in $Q$ for being continuous in the compact but I do not know how to use this to prove what they ask me, could someone help me please? Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you know the Cauchy Integral formula?

Comment: @BobJones Yes, how could I use it?

Comment: If the maximum occurs in the interior, use the Cauchy Integral Formula on a circle completely contained in the square, centered at the maximum. What do you get?

Comment: @BobJones Let $|f(z_0)|:=\text{Max}\{|f(z)|: z\in Q\}$, then $f(z)=\int_{|w-f(z_0)|=r}\frac{f(w)}{w-z}dw$ where $D(f(z_0),r)\subseteq Q$ and so what else can I do?

Comment: Don't forget to divide by $2\pi i$. Now try using $\left|\int f\,dz\right|\leq\int|f||dz|$, and use the parametrization $z=z_0+re^{it}$, and make use of the fact that $f(z_0)$ is at least as large as every value on the circle.

Comment: And it's not $|w-f(z_0)|=r$, it's $|w-z_0|=r$.

Comment: Consider $f(z)=\frac{1}{2}$ (a constant function). What does  happen?

Comment: Do you wanna prove $|f(0)|\leq m_1m_2m_3m_4$ or $|f(0)|\leq m_1+m_2+m_3+m_4$?

Comment: @PotatoHead47 $$ |f(0)|\leq m_1+m_2+m_3+m_4$$ is trivial, since $$|f(0)|\leq \max m_i\le  m_1+m_2+m_3+m_4.$$ He wants to prove $$|f(0)|\leq m_1m_2m_3m_4,$$
but it does'nt hold.

Comment: The 4 inequalities hold only on the sides of the square, neither of them may hold at $z=0$

Comment: By the maximum principle $$ |f(0)|\le \max_{z\in \partial Q} |f(z)|,$$ and $$\max_{z\in \partial Q} |f(z)|= \max m_i.$$